# Using SPIF with custom Content Types

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sitecore

I'm using Sitecore's SharePoint Integration Framework to get items from a SharePoint 2010 installation. The list I want to import is made of an custom Content Type. Selecting the list and mapping the fields works fine. When the items are imported an error is thrown.

```
Sharepoint Provider can't process tree
Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: Item has already been added. 
         Key in dictionary: 'Customization'  Key being added: 'Customization'
```

Has anyone experienced this error before?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it helps, but you might want to check the new version of the module which has just been released: http://sdn.sitecore.net/products/spif/release%20notes.aspx. Also, your problem might be in the list of known issues - verify this as well.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After being unable to solve it I contacted SiteCore support who supplied me with a hotfix to the SPIF framework.
This fixed the problem for me.
I am using SPIF version 111115.